# Disable marker hover in only one marker of highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to convince my highchart to do my bidding and have encountered a problem.

What I want to acchieve:
I want one of the markers of the graph to disappear. I want the line to go through (and break at) one point, but the point is completely irrelevant and I do not want that point to pop up when hovering over it. My current code looks something like this:

```
$(function () {
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'line'
        },   
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            },
            data: [15.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, {
                y: 26.5,
                marker: {
                    enabled: false,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]    
        }]
    });
});
});
```

And all my markers behave the same: they are not visible until I hover over them, at which point they pop up. What I want is for all my markers to behave as they do in the provided code, with the exception of the marker at y=25.6. I want the behaviour of this marker be the same as the behavior I get from all markers when i set

```
hover:{ enabled: false }
```

in my original code. That is, I want the marker to "dissapear" completely.

Thanks in advance for all your help.
Jan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unfortunately bug in Highcharts, see [this](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1610).

Comment: Thank you. Not the answer I was hoping for, but an answer nonetheless.

Answer (score 8):

Try this in your series: `enableMouseTracking: false`

In your case, it would be:

```
series: [{ 
    data: [15.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, {
        enableMouseTracking: false,
        y: 26.5
    }, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]    
}]
```

I hope this helps!

**(Update on 6/23/17):** For those who want to apply this to every series in the chart, not just one, you would do the following:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: { enableMouseTracking: false }
}
```

Comment: @Emiliano: If you apply this to a specific series, as in my first code example, it should only remove that series from the tooltip ... other series you have should show up just fine. The second code example will remove the tooltip for them all.