# Highcharts: Disabling/Enabling enableMouseTracking after initial render

Tags: javascript, highcharts

On initial render of my map using Highmaps, I have enableMouseTracking set to true like so

```
options: {
    series: [{
        mapData: worldMap,
        enableMouseTracking: true
    }]
}
```

And what I'm trying to achieve is to disable enableMouseTracking for a specific country (or the whole map) when that country is selected by the user. And I have tried to achieve this by doing

```
this.chart.series[0].update({
    enableMouseTracking: false
})
```

Unfortunately this is not working. However for some reason, I am able to achieve the opposite, i.e. if I have enableMouseTracking set to false initially, I can enable it after, but not the other way round.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You can checkout this solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17742507/disable-marker-hover-in-only-one-marker-of-highchart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That problem is a Highcharts bug and it is reported here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/12258

As a workaround you can remove listeners on each point of series:

```
series.trackerGroups.forEach(function(key) {
    if (series[key]) {
        // we don't always have dataLabelsGroup
        series[key]
            .removeClass('highcharts-tracker')
            .on('mouseover', Highcharts.noop)
            .on('mouseout', Highcharts.noop);


        series[key].on('touchstart', Highcharts.noop);

    }
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/x0q63ca2/